# Scanner class no lee un file externo- Java

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de utilizar la clase `Scanner` pero, a pesar de que he intentado varios cambios, continúa arrojando `FileNotFoundException`, por favor si alguien tuviera una idea.

Aquí pongo el código

```
package youtube;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scaner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


         String fileName = "C:\\Users\\0d sat\\Desktop\\example.txt";

            File textFile = new File(fileName);

            Scanner in = new Scanner(textFile);

            int value = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Read value: " + value);

            in.nextLine();

            int count = 2;
            while(in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine();

                System.out.println(count + ": " + line);
                count++;
            }

            in.close();
    }
}
```

arroja:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\0d sat\Desktop\example.txt (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
    at youtube.scaner.main(scaner.java:15)
```

Comment: En java los elementos se ponen con slashes normales, pon

C:/Users/0d sat/Desktop/example.txt y procura no usar folders con espacios ya que a veces eso también ocasiona los problemas

Comment: @Sergio1871 en Windows, la forma que utiliza el autor es correcta.

Comment: El error es conciso: tu archivo no existe. Verifica que la ruta provista esté bien. Lo que me parece extraño es que exista un usuario con nombre "0d sat".

Comment: Gracias por la información Luiggi yo varias veces en windows intenté poner el archivo con slashes invertidas y nunca me los reconoció, y cuando las ponía normales agarraba el archivo, no sé que habrá pasado ahí entonces

Comment: intenta acceder a tu archivo desde el CMD, en windows a veces es útil usar el truco deol `~ ` para acortar rutas con espacios ( pues a veces hay más de un espacio y eso es difícil de ver ), yo para hacer este truco normalmente intento con la carpeta "Mis Documentos" que ya tiene espacio en el nombre

Answer (score 1):

te dejo un ejemplo de lectura de un archivo, con Scanner, es  similar a tu código:

```
String fileName = "C:\\TEMP\\folder space\\test.txt";

File textFile = new File(fileName);

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    in = new Scanner(textFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
int count = 2;
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);

    count++;
}
in.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

***FileNotFoundException*** puede deberse a que el fichero no esta o bien no tienes permiso de lectura. Podría ser este segundo caso ya que indicas una ruta dentro del directorio **users** de Windows, prueba a leer un fichero en C: por ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Verifica bien la ruta donde se encuentra tu archivo el error es por que no lo encuentra intenta ponerlo como el ejemplo que te dejare, intenta no poner espacio en los nombres de las carpetas.

Sólo tiene que crear una instancia del escáner y ya está listo para leer el archivo .

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * Programa Java para leer archivos usando la clase de escáner en Java
 * @author
 */
public class ScannerExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

        //Crear una instancia de archivo para referenciar el archivo de texto en Java
        File text = new File("C:/TEMP/test.txt");

        //Creación de la instancia del escáner para leer el archivo en Java
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);

        //Lectura de cada línea de archivo mediante la clase Escáner
        int lineNumber = 1;
        while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Linea " + lineNumber + " :" + line);
            lineNumber++;
        }       

    }   

}
```

Nota: puedes poner la ruta tal como la puse si estas en la unidad C: (C:/TEMP/test.txt)